Automatic configuration of the dropdown list location in Dropdown antd
I want to set up my drop-down list so that it always unfolds downwards. Using the autoAdjustOverflow={false} property, I get it. But how do I get the same behavior for the second nesting level?
Here is an example of the code:
stackblitz
I need the "submenu" to open from the bottom, how can I do this?
